# Excel VBA Appending data to single Array

Tags: excel, vba

Am trying to parse an excel file using Excel VBA.

Here is the sample sata
[image]

I did some research and found you can assign ranges to array like

```
Arrayname = Range("A1:D200")
```

But am looking for some thing more dynamic, like add the below multiple ranges to a single array.
and my final array will be a single array/table with n is number of rows from all ranges and 4 columns.

Can any one please prvide me a example.
Thank you in adavance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for more information about moving data between ranges and variables so that is the question I will attempt to answer.

Create a new workbook.  Leave Sheet1 empty; set cell B3 of Sheet2 to "abc" and set cells C4 to F6 of Sheet3 to ="R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN()

Open the VB Editor, create a module and copy the follow code to it.  Run macro `Demo01()`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Demo01()

  Dim ColURV As Long
  Dim InxWkSht As Long
  Dim RowURV As Long
  Dim UsedRangeValue As Variant

  ' For each worksheet in the workbook
  For InxWkSht = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    With Worksheets(InxWkSht)
      Debug.Print .Name
      If .UsedRange Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "  Empty sheet"
      Else
        Debug.Print "  Row range: " & .UsedRange.Row & " to " & _
                            .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
        Debug.Print "  Col range: " & .UsedRange.Column & " to " & _
                            .UsedRange.Column + .UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1
      End If
      UsedRangeValue = .UsedRange.Value
      If IsEmpty(UsedRangeValue) Then
        Debug.Print "  Empty sheet"
      ElseIf VarType(UsedRangeValue) > vbArray Then
        ' More than one cell used
        Debug.Print "  Values:"
        For RowURV = 1 To UBound(UsedRangeValue, 1)
          Debug.Print "  ";
          For ColURV = 1 To UBound(UsedRangeValue, 2)
            Debug.Print "  " & UsedRangeValue(RowURV, ColURV);
          Next
          Debug.Print
        Next
      Else
        ' Must be single cell worksheet
        Debug.Print "  Value = " & UsedRangeValue
      End If

    End With
  Next

End Sub
```

The following will appear in the Immediate Window:

```
Sheet1
  Row range: 1 to 1
  Col range: 1 to 1
  Empty sheet
Sheet2
  Row range: 3 to 3
  Col range: 2 to 2
  Value = abc
Sheet3
  Row range: 4 to 6
  Col range: 3 to 5
  Values:
    R4C3  R4C4  R4C5
    R5C3  R5C4  R5C5
    R6C3  R6C4  R6C5
```

If you work through the macro and study the output you will get an introduction to loading a range to a variant.  The points I particularly want you to note are:

- The variable to which the range is loaded is of type Variant.  I have never tried loading a single range to a Variant array since the result may not be an array.  Even if it works, I would find this confusing.
- Sheet1 is empty but the used range tells you than cell A1 is used.  However, the variant to which I have loaded the sheet is empty.
- The variant only becomes an array if the range contains more than one cell.  Note: the array will ALWAYS be two dimensional even if the range is a single row or a single column.
- The lower bounds of the array are ALWAYS 1.
- The column and row dimensions are not standard with the rows as dimension 1 and the columns as dimension 2.
- If there is any doubt about the nature of the range being loaded, you must use IsEmpty and VarType to test its nature.

You may also like to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16607070/973283.  Skim the explanations of macros `Demo01()` and `Demo02()` which are not relevant to you but set the context.  Macro `Demo03()` shows the advanced technique of loading multiple worksheets to a jagged array.

Now create a new worksheet and leave it with the default name of `Sheet4`.

Add the follow code to the module.  Run macro `Demo02()`.

```
Sub Demo02()

  Dim ColOut As Long
  Dim OutputValue() As String
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowOut As Long
  Dim Stg As String

  ReDim OutputValue(5 To 10, 3 To 6)

  For RowOut = LBound(OutputValue, 1) To UBound(OutputValue, 1)
    For ColOut = LBound(OutputValue, 2) To UBound(OutputValue, 2)
      OutputValue(RowOut, ColOut) = RowOut + ColOut
    Next
  Next

  With Worksheets("Sheet4")
    Set Rng = .Range("A1:D6")
  End With
  Rng.Value = OutputValue

  With Worksheets("Sheet4")
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(8, 2), .Cells(12, 4))
  End With
  Rng.Value = OutputValue

  With Worksheets("Sheet4")
    Stg = "C" & 14 & ":G" & 20
    Set Rng = .Range(Stg)
  End With
  Rng.Value = OutputValue

End Sub
```

Although this macro writes an array to a worksheet, many of the points apply for the opposite direction.  The points I particularly want you to note are:

- For output, the array does not have to be Variant nor do the lower bounds have to be 1.  I have made OutputValue a String array so the values output are strings.  Change OutputValue to a Variant array and rerun the macro to see the effect.
- I have used three different ways of creating the range to demonstrate some of your choices.
- If you specify a range as I have, the worksheet is one of the properties of the range.  That is why I can take `Rng.Value = OutputValue` outside the `With ... End With` and still have the data written to the correct worksheet.
- When copying from a range to a variant, Excel sets the dimensions of the variant as appropriate.  When copying from an array to a range, it is your responsibility to get the size of the range correct.  With the second range, I lost data.  With the third range, I gained N/As.

I hope the above gives you an idea of your options.  If I understand your requirement correctly, you will have to:

- Load the entire worksheet to Variant
- Create a new Array of the appropriate size
- Selectively copy data from the Variant to the Array.

Come back withh questions if anything is unclear.